# Conditional set in Terraform with Helm

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to set helm values in terraform but for a specific condition. For example, I want the snippet below to execute only in a specific use case. otherwise, I want Terraform to ignore it.
My usecase is that I want to let the end user the will run this Terraform to choose if he want to provision an internal Azure LB or a regular LB.
If regular -- The public IP that also created in the code will be set in the values.
If Internal -- Azure will generate automatically a private IP and set it as the "external IP" of the LB.

```
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = mypuclicip
  }
```

Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: What is the specific use case? Usually ternary operator helps in these situations, but I would like to see the condition added to the question. :)

Comment: Sure, I just edited my question.

Comment: And would you mind adding the LB part of the code and the part where the public IP gets created?

Comment: @MarkoE This is the same code for the external LB (my goal is to provision an nginx controller). but I just add the annotation to make the LB behave like an internal LB.

Comment: So an attribute from a resource that was created previously is not required for this to work? And based on what you want to add the annotation? Value of a variable? Something else?

Comment: @MarkoE Exactly. In addition, If I'll try to set the snippet above + the annotation of the internal LB it will lead to an error. (can't assign public IP with internal LB annotation). 
and yes, this is a value of specific Terraform env.

Comment: I still can't quite grasp where the values will be coming from so it's hard to suggest a solution that would work. Does the value for the `name` differ between the internal LB and when a public IP is set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It feels like Terraform should have a more ergonomic way of doing this, but I believe the best solution you have available is to use a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
dynamic "set" {
  for_each = <condition> ? [mypublicip] : []
  content {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = set.value
  }
}
```